# How do I rotate my logs despite having running processes?

Tags: process, rails, logs, logrotate

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.  I have this Rails project and my logs are exploding out of control size-wise ...

```
myuser@myapp:~$ ls -al /home/rails/myapp/log/
total 3118220
drwxr-xr-x  2 rails rails       4096 Jul  3 22:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 rails rails       4096 Sep 21 17:21 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 rails rails          0 Jun 22 10:22 development.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 rails rails      14960 Jun  1 22:39 development.log.1
-rw-rw-r--  1 rails rails          0 Oct 22  2016 .keep
-rw-r--r--  1 rails rails  178464887 Oct 11 10:00 production.log
-rw-r--r--  1 rails rails    8615654 Jul  3 22:31 production.log.1
-rw-r--r--  1 rails rails  640621243 Jun 29 13:16 production.log.2.gz
-rw-rw-r--  1 rails rails 2016391330 Oct 11 10:09 sidekiq.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 rails rails  348853619 Jul  3 22:31 sidekiq.log.1
-rw-rw-r--  1 rails rails          0 Jul  3 22:31 test.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 rails rails      54246 Jul  3 22:31 test.log.1
```

I have set up this log rotation rule ..l

```
myuser@myapp:~$ cat /etc/logrotate.d/myapp
/home/rails/myapp/log/*.log {
    daily
    missingok
    compress
    notifempty
    rotate 12
    create
    delaycompress
    missingok
    su rails rails
    postrotate
        pkill -USR1 -u rails unicorn
    endscript
}
```

And yet things still aren't rotating, despite my including the "skill" command.  It has been theorized that things aren't rotating because there are running processes, for example, the below

```
myuser@myapp:~$ ps -elf | grep sidekiq
1 S rails    23864     1  1  80   0 - 254353 -     Oct10 ?        00:10:49 sidekiq 5.0.0 myapp [1 of 1 busy]
```

I would like to know how to rotate my logs despite the running processes.  If that's not the problem, then I'd just like to have the logs rotate.

Comment: Best to read the logs and figure out what is filling them and resolve that issue. If you are not going to read the logs disable them.

Comment: We have a lot of audit information that we have to run reports on hence the big logs.  So it is not an option to log less.  Rotating is a fairly common thing, so why isn't the above configuration working?

Comment: At a minimum clean up those options. You have "missingok" twice and what is "su rails rails" doing there ? is it part of the postscript ? I would specify a mode, owner, and group on teh create line. If you are not going to specify anything, then it is the same as defaults, and can be removed. I am not sure how pkill knows who USR1 is.

Comment: "USR1" isn't a user, at least its not intended to be.  I thought the "-u" flag that follows it with the "rails" user specifies who the user is.

Comment: Did you clean up the options ? Is it working ?

Comment: Hi, I did try removing the duplicate options you noted but alas, the logs grow ever bigger.

Comment: large log size = look at what and why you are logging so much / what is filling the logs. Your question is about log rotate. Did we fix the original question of log rotation ? If not repost your config file.

Comment: try executing the logrotate manually with verbose option. you'll know why wasn't it rotated

Answer (score 1):

The running process most probably prevents the logs from being rotated. You have two options. Either restart the process (sidekiq) in the postrotate section or use the **copytruncate** option to truncate the original file in-place instead of deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options.

- Try to rotate logs within your Ruby project by using standard [libraries](https://github.com/lenny/log4jruby). This minimizes data loss which happens in other options.
- For some reason, if its not possible, then use copytruncate directive in logrotate config. This will work only if log file is opened with [O_APPEND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518219/empty-a-file-while-in-use-in-linux) flag.
- If none of the above works, in postrotate section, restart the process or pass a [signal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122929/emptying-a-file-without-disrupting-the-pipe-writing-to-it) to your script which will handle re-opening of log files (so that you don't have to restart the process)